# select descendente hasta llegar a 1 - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

**tengo un select que se va sumando uno en uno de forma dinamica hasta llegar al valor maximo del input , ahora necesito que sea lo contrario que se vaya resetanto hasta llegar a uno, he intentado pero no he podido, solo necesito que se vaya restanto los select dinamicos hasta llegar a uno, lo he intentado pero no he podido se me descontrola el algoritmo, en codesendbox muestra como tengo el codigo actualmente, donde al seleccionar un select con algun valor este genera otro select con el valor que sigue hasta llegar al valor total del input**

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-christian-wqxo2?file=/src/App.js:0-2625

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: []
};
const Test = () => {
  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco);

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }

    return arr;
  };
  const setSelect = (value) => {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setarraySelect([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="numberIni" type="number" />
        <input type="submit" value="Generar select" />
      </form>
      {numberIni && (
        <div>
          <select onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
            <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
            {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
              .fill(1)
              .map((value, key) => {
                return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1}</option>;
              })}
          </select>

          {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
            .fill(1)
            .map((value, key2) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {arraySelect[key2] && (
                    <>
                      <select
                        onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)}
                        name=""
                        id=""
                      >
                        <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                        {arraySelect[key2].map((value, key3) => {
                          return (
                            <option value={arraySelect[key2][key3]}>
                              {arraySelect[key2][key3]}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}
                      </select>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      )}

      {numberIni && (
        <input onClick={() => resetForm()} type="button" value="Reiniciar" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Es decir al dar reset que suceda el proceso en reversa de como se formo el grupo de selects original?

Comment: volvi a crear la pregunta pero trate de ser mas especifico:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492503/mi-select-dinamico-esta-funcinando-de-forma-ascendente-ahora-quiero-funcione-de