# mi select dinamico esta funcinando de forma ascendente ahora quiero funcione de forma descendete - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un select dinamico que funciona de la siguiente forma explico:

1. hay un input donde agrego un valor "X" y este me genera automáticamente un select con la cantidad de valores que agregue en el input
2. cuando selecciono un valor del select este me carga otro select dinamico donde me aparece los números faltantes de forma ascendente y asi hasta seleccionar el ultimo numero.

ejemplo de como esta funcionando de forma ascendente:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-christian-wqxo2?file=/src/App.js:0-2625

Lo que necesito "descendente":

1. cambiar mi código para que me haga lo contrario, si coloco un valor "X" en el input debe cargarme en el select todos los valores pero de forma descendente.
2. al seleccionar un valor en el select este debe cargarme otro select con los valores faltantes pero de forma descendente y así consecutivamente hasta llegar a uno.

mi código actual como funciona de forma ascendente:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: []
};
const Test = () => {
  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco);

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }

    return arr;
  };
  const setSelect = (value) => {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setarraySelect([]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="numberIni" type="number" />
        <input type="submit" value="Generar select" />
      </form>
      {numberIni && (
        <div>
          <select onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
            <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
            {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
              .fill(1)
              .map((value, key) => {
                return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1}</option>;
              })}
          </select>

          {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
            .fill(1)
            .map((value, key2) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {arraySelect[key2] && (
                    <>
                      <select
                        onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)}
                        name=""
                        id=""
                      >
                        <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                        {arraySelect[key2].map((value, key3) => {
                          return (
                            <option value={arraySelect[key2][key3]}>
                              {arraySelect[key2][key3]}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}
                      </select>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      )}

      {numberIni && (
        <input onClick={() => resetForm()} type="button" value="Reiniciar" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejemplo Funcionando: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-carlos-098li?file=/src/App.js

En este caso debes reescribir el `getArray` para que vaya introduciendo los valores en ese orden, iniciando en el valor que recibe como parametro restando el iterador (y 1)

```js
const getArray = (value) => {
  const numValue = parseInt(value, 10);
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numValue - 1; i++) {
    arr.push(numValue - i - 1)
  }
  if (arr.length) {
    return arr;
  }
};
```

Y en caso de que el primer select si quieres que también sea inverso sería (haciendo lo mismo, partiendo por el valor de referencia y restando el iterador):

```
<select onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
  <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
  {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
    .fill(1)
    .map((value, key) => {
      return <option value={numberIni - key}>{numberIni - key}</option>;
    })}
</select>
```

Comment: buen dia, tengo un inconveniente respecto a la misma pregunta, es que necesito no cargue por defecto cada select dinamico "seleccione" si no que haya un boton que diga siguiente por cada select dinamico.  como seria, lo he intentado pero no lo he logrado.

Comment: Hola Giovanni, recuerda que si una respuesta soluciona el problema planteado en la pregunta debes marcarla como aceptada y/o upvotearla. Eso que preguntas es un poco más complicado que lo que habías preguntado acá, te invito a crear una nueva pregunta :)

Comment: listo muchas gracias, ya cree la nueva pregunta , te envio la pregunta por si puedes ayudarme https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/492668/mi-select-dinamico-esta-genrando-select-automaticos-al-seleccionar-un-valor-qu