# mi select dinamico esta genrando select automaticos al seleccionar un valor , quiero agregar un boton por cada select - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un select dinamico que funciona de la siguiente forma explico:

hay un input donde agrego un valor "X" y este me genera automáticamente un select con la cantidad de valores que agregue en el input

cuando selecciono un valor del select este me carga otro select dinamico donde me aparece los números faltantes de forma ascendente y asi hasta seleccionar el ultimo numero.

ejemplo de como esta funcionando: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wu-cb2yv?file=/src/App.js:0-2772

Lo que necesito "agregar un boton para que me genere select siguiente":

Necesito que los selects no se generen automáticamente si no que haya un boton que diga crear y cada vez que oprima el boton genera el select siguiente.

mi código actual:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: []
};
const Test = () => {
  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    const numValue = parseInt(value, 10);
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numValue - 1; i++) {
      arr.push(numValue - i - 1);
    }
    if (arr.length) {
      return arr;
    }
  };
  const setSelect = (value) => {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value - 1);
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setarraySelect([]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="numberIni" type="number" />

        <input type="submit" value="Generar select" />
      </form>
      {numberIni && (
        <div>
          <select onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
            <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
            {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
              .fill(1)
              .map((value, key) => {
                return (
                  <option value={numberIni - key}>{numberIni - key}</option>
                );
              })}
          </select>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
            crear
          </button>
          {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
            .fill(1)
            .map((value, key2) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {arraySelect[key2] && (
                    <>
                      <select
                        onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)}
                        name=""
                        id=""
                      >
                        <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                        {arraySelect[key2].map((value, key3) => {
                          return (
                            <option value={arraySelect[key2][key3]}>
                              {arraySelect[key2][key3]}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}
                      </select>
                      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">
                        crear
                      </button>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      )}

      {numberIni && (
        <input onClick={() => resetForm()} type="button" value="Reiniciar" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejemplo funcionando: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-tree-hiiek?file=/src/App.js

A diferencia del código anterior debes guardar una referencia al valor que ha cambiado. Por eso definiremos un nuevo estado que se llamará `selectedNumbers`.

```js
const [selectedNumbers, setSelectedNumbers] = useState([]);
```

Ahora, hay 3 cambios importantes:

- **Cambio 0**: Definimos una función que reciba el index del select que estamos manipulando y el valor para actualizarlo, basados en otras funciones hice la siguiente función

```js
const handleChange = (index, value) => {
  const tmpSelectedNumbers = [...selectedNumbers];
  tmpSelectedNumbers[index] = value;
  setSelectedNumbers(tmpSelectedNumbers);
};
```

- **Cambio 1** Antes, al cambiar el change hacías `setSelect`, ahora como debemos esperar a presionar crear vamos a guardar ese valor, entonces cambiaríamos:

```js
// Nuestro Index varia, si es el primero ponemos 0, si es el del loop usamos el iterador (+1 porque el 0 ya está tomado por el primero)
<select
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e.target.value)}
>
```

**Cambio 2:*** Finalmente, agregamos la funcionalidad al botón de crear tomando en cuenta el valor seleccionado PARA ese específico select:

```js
// Nuestro Index varia, si es el primero ponemos 0, si es el del loop usamos el iterador (+1 porque el 0 ya está tomado por el primero)
<button
  className="btn btn-success"
  onClick={() => { setSelect(selectedNumbers[index]); }}
>
  crear
</button>
```

Y ahí ya funcionaría.

Comment: muchas gracias, que libros o articulos me recomiendas para poder resolver problemas parecidos..

Comment: Han sido 2 problemas distintos, ambos se van resolviendo con practica :). Uno era de Algoritmos y el otro era específicamente de React. Para el de Algoritmos puedes buscar problemas de Algoritmos en general en Google (no tengo uno en especial) para el de React puedes Leer la documentación súper buena: https://es.reactjs.org/. También puedes ver los canales y cursos de LeonidasEsteban, HolaMundo (Nicolas Schurman), MoureDev.

Comment: Hola joseglego no he podido solucionar esta pregunta , si me puedes ayudar te lo agradeceria https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494116/me-toca-seleccionar-dos-veces-dos-valores-en-el-select-para-que-me-reconozca-el